# Why it gives an error of Segmentation Fault but for only some runs of code(or we can say for some input cases)?

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list, segmentation-fault

Why does it show segmentation Fault for only 1 test case out of 15 test cases.
The next and the head pointers are accessible, i didn't even alter any of the in-editable pointers.

Error - **Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x0000000000401364 in compare_lists (head2=,
head1=0x192f5b0) at Solution.cpp:70
`line 70 while(temp->next != nullptr && temp2->next != nullptr){`**

```
bool compare_lists(SinglyLinkedListNode* head1, SinglyLinkedListNode* head2)
{
    SinglyLinkedListNode* temp = head1;
    SinglyLinkedListNode* temp2 = head2;
    bool abc;
    int i1 = 0;
    int i2 = 0;
    while (temp->next != nullptr && temp2->next != nullptr) {
        if (temp->data == temp2->data && i1 == i2) {
            ++i1;
            ++i2;
            abc = true;
            temp = temp->next;
            temp2 = temp2->next;
        }
        else {
            abc = false;
            temp = temp->next;
            temp2 = temp2->next;
        }
    }
    return abc;
}
```

Comment: You could check that `head1` and `head2` are not `nullptr`

Comment: @Damien yes, that was the issue

Comment: Your function has undefined behaviour if any input list has fewer than two elements. Its result in other cases only depends on the k:th element of the lists, where k+1 is the length of the shorter list. (Also, the purpose of `i1` and `i2` is mysterious, as they always have the same value.)

Comment: @molbdnilo the i1 and i2 are there to count the number elements of linked list. And yes my code is in progress  so thanks for the suggestions

Comment: @Noob_Coder_189 Both variables hold the number of elements in the shorter list. You don't need to count the elements; if you reach the end of one list, but haven't reached the end of the other, they are of unequal length.

Comment: @molbdnilo yes i have to compare the elements of the list if the length is dissimilar and the elements do not map, then i have to return false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before assigning a node to its `next` neighbor, you should check it for null.

```
if (temp->next != nullptr)
    temp = temp->next; 
if (temp2->next != nullptr) 
    temp2 = temp2->next;
```

Little update: That doesn't seem to be the problem, I thought you were checking `temp` and `temp2` themselves for null in your loop condition. In that case, your code will crash if one of them is originally null. i.e. one list is empty.

Comment: loop itself will get terminated if the next neighbour is null

Comment: The loop condition will be checked after assigning `temp = temp->next; `, which causes your crash.

Comment: keep in mind `while (temp->next != nullptr && temp2->next != nullptr)` could throw an exxception if `temp` or `temp2` are initially null, not their `next` neighbors.

Comment: yes but the test case giving the error does not have any null pointers for temp or temp->next.

Comment: I don't understand how this solves the problem. Within the loop, `temp->next` and `temp2->next` are guaranteed to not be nullptr. Even worse, since you use the `next` in your while condition, you would end up in an infinite loop this way, no? The only problem I see is if the initial pointers are null.

Comment: @Cedric You're correct. I originally misread his loop condition thinking it checks `temp` and `temp2` themselves. Hence my follow up comment. If it does that then checking for `next` neighbor will be necessary.

Comment: @Cedric i changed the loop condition thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your function has undefined behaviour if any input list has fewer than two elements.
Its result in other cases only depends on the k:th element of the lists, where k+1 is the length of the shorter list.
You also don't need to count the elements; if you reach the end of one list, but haven't reached the end of the other, they are of unequal length.

Note that the lists are equal if and only if you reach the end of both lists without encountering a differing element.

A shorter definition:

```
bool equal_lists(const SinglyLinkedListNode* head1, const SinglyLinkedListNode* head2)
{
    while (head1 != nullptr && head2 != nullptr) {
        if (head1->data != head2->data) {
            break;
        }
        head1 = head1->next;
        head2 = head2->next;
    }
    return head1 == nullptr && head2 == nullptr;
}
```

Comment: That note was kept in mind and was coded accordingly,your code is better and has less time and space complexity than me, i will keep in mind the above points which you have mentioned. Thanks, From Noob_Coder_189

Comment: My code is working fine i did a little tweak to the while loop condition(changed it to temp != nullptr && temp2 != nullptr.) I just wanted to know why was there a segmentation fault for future references.